# C++ OpenMP merge sort

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, mergesort

I have written parallel implementation of merge sort but for some reasons that I cannot understand sometimes it finishes properly, and sometimes it crashes. Whats more interesting following code sometimes seems to crash AFTER it has sorted the array (the array gets printed and then code stops working).

Could anyone help me diagnose a problem? I guess I messed something with threads and they are not ending properly?

```
void printArray (int* a, int elements) {
    for(int i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", a[i]);
    }
}

void merge2(int a[], int l, int middle, int r) {
    int leftIterator = l;
    int rightIterator = middle+1;
    int k = 0;

    int* tmp = new int[(r - l)]; 
    while (leftIterator <= middle &&  rightIterator <= r) { 
        if (a[leftIterator] < a[rightIterator]) {
            tmp[k] = a[leftIterator];
            leftIterator++;
        }
        else {
            tmp[k] = a[rightIterator];
            rightIterator++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    if (leftIterator <= middle) { 
        while (leftIterator <= middle) {
            tmp[k] = a[leftIterator];
            leftIterator++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    else {
            while (rightIterator <= r) {
                tmp[k] = a[rightIterator];
                rightIterator++;
                k++;
            }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= (r - l); i++)
        a[l + i] = tmp[i];
}

void merge_sort(int a[], int l, int r) {
    if (l != r) {
    int middle= (l + r) / 2; //find middle element
    #pragma omp parallel sections
    { 
       #pragma omp section
       merge_sort(a, l, middle);
       #pragma omp section
        merge_sort(a, middle + 1, r);
    }
    merge2(a, l, middle, r);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int elements = 10;
    int a[10] = { 10,2,1,5,6,3,4,9,8,7 };
    merge_sort(a, 0, elements-1);
    printArray(a, elements); // print sorted array
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you add crash message and crash stack trace?

Comment: To be honest I'm little confused with that. Usually I don't use code::blocks. All I got was:

    Stack level 0, frame at 0x112fc56:
 eip = 0x4017a4 in merge_sort (C:\Users\Martin\Desktop\lab5 qs\main.cpp:94); saved eip 0xfd4c0040
 called by frame at 0x112fc5a
 source language c++.
 Arglist at 0x112fc4e, args: a=0x360029, l=3538944, r=718274560
 Locals at 0x112fc4e, Previous frame's sp is 0x112fc56
 Saved registers:
  ebp at 0x112fc4e, eip at 0x112fc52

Comment: So the l and r are way out of bound, but on the other hand this error happens all time when I put breakpoint anywhere in merge_sort function. When I put breakpoint somewhere in main function i.e before return 0 program executes properly every time.

Comment: I don't have any problem running it on g++ by cygwin without changing anything on your code(only added include stdio.h), and your code seems fine for me (not sure of the perf but I am no expert). Your problem might come from your environment. Try to run the code without this specific openMP instruction, check your compiler compatibility with openMP, or use cygwin :)

Comment: Thanks, running it on cygwin/Microsoft's Visual C++ resolved the issue. Not sure what was wrong with minGW i was using (some other algorithms using openmp were working properly) but yeah. It was the case. Thanks once again